# Mutexes and lambda functions in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, mutex

When dealing with concurrency problems I often use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` and `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, no problem with both.

I also extended `std::mutex` to be able to use it as follow:

```
mutex.protect([](){
    // my protected code here
}) ;
```

It locks the mutex and releases it around the lambda call.

Is such a similar behavior already implemented inside boost or the standard library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost Thread has this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.with_lock_guard

You can use it like you'd expect:

```
std::mutex mx;

boost::with_lock_guard(mx, []{
    // protected stuff
});
```

It even supports the usual INVOKE semantics:

```
int foo(int,double) { return 42; }

// ...

int answer = boost::with_lock_guard(mx, foo, 3, 3.14);
```

#### Manual Standard Library Only implementation

You can easily add a thing like this yourself:

```
template <typename M, typename F, typename... Args> 
    auto my_with_lock_guard(M& mx, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        std::lock_guard<M> lk(mx);
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

If the standard ever adopts a proposal like this you can easily swap it out.

Comment: Perfect, entirely fits my needs. I missed this boost feature during my search.

Comment: This also has the advantage of avoiding a common mistake with std::lock_guard, namely, not declaring a variable when using it.

Comment: I believe your manual implementation requires C++14, otherwise I get the error message: `error: ‘with_lock_guard’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type
     auto with_lock_guard(M& mx, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
                                                      ^`
... 

`note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14`

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Of course. Just specify the return type for c++11

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is **protect** code in a **smaller scope** inside a function you don't need to extend mutex by writing your own protect function. You can just do as below, use curly braces to create a local scope, and when the scope is exited the mutex will automatically be unlocked in an exception safe way.

```
double process_func() { 
// do some stuff
    { //start a new scope block
      std::lock_guard<my_mutex> g; // mutex is locked here.
      []() { } // your lambda that needs to be protected
    } // Mutex is released here.
// do more stuff
}
```

Of course this has the disadvantage over your custom function that,
it is difficult to maintain. Someone can come later and inject more code without knowing what they are doing.

Comment: That's what I used to do, but for any reason I found this approach pretty unattractive, I was searching for a more straightforward one but I'd like to avoid stepping out of the standards

Comment: I don't see it in the standard lock_guard or unique_lock. I do not see any downside to extending it using your protect() method. If I were you the one thing I would test out is the new std::lock http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock which takes in multiple lockables and locks all or none to avoid deadlocks. But you should be good as long as you extend as you would have all the original lock(), unlock() , try_lock() methods .

Comment: I did not see it in the standard either. I don't really like extending such low level objects but as you noticed this does not alter the other approaches of locking.

Comment: @Falco key thing to realize that extending types doesn't imply adding members. See [The Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm)